# Difficulties imposing appropriate width for elements in a div section in HTML5

Tags: css, html, nav

I am experiencing a problem imposing the correct width for a certain div. My code is the following:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div class="flt-sec">
                <a href="index.html" class='left'>home</a>
                <section>
                          <p> Our offers are the best on the city !! Check out our amazing activities !!! </p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="flt-sec">
                <a href="_web/playa.html" >La Playa !</a>
                <section class='inv'>
                                 <p> One of the best in the world, if not the best, garanty !!! </p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="flt-sec">
                <a href="_web/ciudad.html" >La Ciudad !</a>
                <section>
                               <p> Feel what your granpa felt in his youth, back to the fifties baby !! </p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="flt-sec">
                <a href="_web/excursion.html" >La Excursion !</a>
                <section class='inv'>
                            <p> I thought pirate of the carabbean was all a hollywood set up. No ! We got it all wrong !! </p>
                </section>
            </div>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

And the CSS is the following:

```
.flt-sec
{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
nav
{
    width:100%;
}
nav a:link
{
    width:100%;
}
    section 
{
    width:100%;
}
```

But even with this I am getting a `nav:a` tag overflowing at the end of the `div` container, as follows:

[image]

The other `div` sections seem to be OK and behaving the way they should (the `nav:a` and the sub-section are both respecting the div container width)

Comment: Do you have a link to the site or a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) you can post?

Comment: I'll try to upload it on-line and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have width 25% per nav link but yet you appear to have set padding too. This padding will cause these links to exceed their combined width of 100%

Comment: You're right ! Thanks ! Although I didn't set padding in the section tag and yet the three first nav tags match prefectly their respective sections... But removing the padding fixed the problem !

Comment: Glad to help. As it fixed your problem could you mark the answer as correct as other users.